# How to create asp.net hyperlink that downloads on click

Tags: asp.net

I have some code that produces URL links based on what the user has searched, this links are to file paths in an internal file directory.

When we use the website in IE, when clicked the links download the file, but using Chrome nothing happens on click  - but if the link is copied and pasted into a new tab the file downloads. Chrome is the preference browser as the HTML and CSS used is only compatible in Chrome and not our versions of IE.

Last time my question got downvoted, please comment the reason why if this is to be downvoted again.

Below is the code which I suspect needs some changing...

```
Response.Write("<a href = """ & RS("URL") & """>" & RS("NAME") & "</a>" & vbnewline)
```

Comment: You might want to quit using `Response.Write` to create objects on your site... It bezomes [a mess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51895276/response-write-link-to-file-download-not-working-on-chrome)

Comment: Okay, what is a better alternative?

Comment: MVC, Core, Webforms?